# OpenCL Example Procet with POCL

Tags: opencl, pocl

I built and installed pocl on ubuntu, and also checked it with clinfo command, everything is normal.
I'm new to OpenCL, I couldn't build an example that was copied from example0 after installed.
I did not find dependency libraries of examples in the source code.
Actually, there are three examples in pocl source code but I'm confused about CMake dependency hierarchy of it.
Please help me to create an example opencl-pocl project.

Comment: Please help me to create an example.

Comment: Please elaborate the steps you followed and tell us the error you're getting